# Recompile bootstrap with visual studio bower

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bower, asp.net-core-mvc

Running latest rc1 of ASP.NET MVC core with bower as the client-side package manager.  Made a change to bootstrap's variables.less (to change font) but the change is not showing in the browser.  What do I need to do to get the font change to take effect?

Answer (score 0):

You need something that compiles the less file.

I did it by installing the visual studio extension named [Web Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler).

It will compile everything to a css file which you can include in the `bundleconfig.json`